# Oracle APEX use button to change report source sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

On the report page of my Oracle APEX application, the report source is defined by sql with

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 ... FROM TABLE1
```

When the user clicks a button, for example, button 'Sort', I would like to add JOIN, WHERE and ORDER BY clauses to the report source sql.

The new report source after the button click event should be

```
SELECT VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 ... FROM TABLE1 
JOIN TABLE2 WHERE ID='123' ORDER BY VALUE2 ASC
```

How do you achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need separate button to do the filtering, sorting? It can be achieved by Dynamic report itself.

Comment: This is part of our assignment. We are required to implement separate sort or filtering, such as sort by nearest distance first, which is not covered in the Dynamic report by default.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only change filtering, sorting, visible column list and so on use Interactive Report feature. If you really want change query text choose "PL/SQL Function Returning SQL Query" as the report implementation type and create some code

```
DECLARE
  l_col_list  VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_join      VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_where     VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_col_List := ....;
  l_join := ....;
  l_where := ....;
  RETURN 'SELECT ' || l_col_list || ' FROM ' || l_join || ' WHERE ' || l_where;
END;
```

[image]

Example page: [apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:5](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:5)

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. How can the Source sql be changed at runtime through a button click dynamic action?

Comment: You can use hidden items to store select_list, join and where values . Change it on button click and re-submit page.

Comment: Could you please explain about using hidden items a bit further as I'm quite new to Apex. For example, by default when the report page is loaded, it should show all values I mean every data row from the data table. If the user clicks a custom sorting button, say "Sort by Nearest Distance First", then it activates the join and where, and show it in the order.

Comment: Create new items on page with type = hidden. For example, you can create one item named :Pxx_MY_QUERY. Then create PL/SQL process on button click and set item value with complete Query text. Also modify Region Source to BEGIN RETURN :Pxx_MY_QUERY; END; It should works.